ARIMA(12,0,0) - Missing 14th param? Fitted values <> Calculated
I have an ARIMA(12, 0, 0) model created in R.   I calculated the fitted values to be
$$\hat{y}(t) = \phi_1 y(t-1) + \phi_2 y(t-2) + \ldots + \phi_{12} y(t-12) + \text{intercept}$$
Comparing my calculations with the last 10 fitted values of the model results in a constant difference (the 10 differences are the same).  Why would there be any differences?  Trying to figure this out, I came across the equation that the
$$ \text{AIC} = 2k - 2\ln(L) $$
where k is the number of parameters and L is the maximum likelihood.  When I solve for k, I get 14 while expecting 13 (twelve lags and an intercept).  What is this 14th parameter? Where would I find it in R. Does it explain the error? The code to reproduce the issue follows:
library(readxl)
library(curl)
library(dplyr)
url <- "https://img1.wsimg.com/blobby/go/e5e77e0b-59d1-44d9-ab25-4763ac982e53/downloads/e1fcc664-eaa1-48ed-b682-88e0c33db496/ie_data.xls?ver=1733242673788"
temp_file <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")
curl_download(url, temp_file)
shiller_data <- suppressWarnings(suppressMessages({
  read_excel(
    temp_file,
    sheet = "Data",
    range = "A8:V1856",
    col_types = c(
      "numeric",
      "numeric",
      "numeric",
      "numeric",
      "numeric",
      "numeric",
      "numeric",
      "numeric",
      "numeric",
      "numeric",
      "numeric",
      "numeric",
      "numeric",
      "skip",
      "numeric",
      "skip",
      "numeric",
      "numeric",
      "numeric",
      "numeric",
      "numeric",
      "numeric"
    )
  )
}))
colnames(shiller_data) <- c(
  "Date",
  "SPCompP",
  "D",
  "E",
  "CPI",
  "DateFraction",
  "LongRateGS10",
  "RealP",
  "RealD",
  "RealTRP",
  "RealE",
  "RealTRScaledE",
  "CAPE",
  "TRCAPE",
  "ExcessCAPEYld",
  "BondReturns",
  "RealBondReturns",
  "StockRealRet10Y",
  "BondRealRet10Y",
  "ExcessRealRet10Y"
)

DateFraction2Date <- function(dateFraction) {
  y = floor(dateFraction)
  m = ceiling((dateFraction - y)*12) + 1
  idx <- m > 12
  y[idx] <- y[idx] + 1
  m[idx] <- 1
  out <- as.Date(paste0(y, "-",m,"-1"), format = "%Y-%m-%d") - 1
  return(out) 
}

shiller_data <- shiller_data %>% mutate(Date1 = DateFraction2Date(DateFraction))
inflation <- shiller_data$CPI[2:nrow(shiller_data)]/shiller_data$CPI[1:(nrow(shiller_data) -1)] - 1 
inflation_ts <- ts(inflation, start = c(lubridate::year(shiller_data$Date1[2]), lubridate::month(shiller_data$Date1[2])), frequency = 12)

window_data <- inflation_ts[1:360]
ar_model <- Arima(window_data, order = c(12, 0, 0))
fitted10 <- ar_model$fitted[351:360]
calcFitted10 <- numeric(10)
for (i in 351:360) {
 calcFitted10[i-350] <- sum(window_data[(i-12):(i-1)] * ar_model$coef[12:1]) + ar_model$coef[13]
}
fitted10 - calcFitted10
implied_params <- (ar_model$aic - ar_model$loglik*-2)/2

The data in this example is from Shiller's CAPE data.
Summary: Why aren't the

fitted10 - calcFitted10

all zeros?  Is it because the

implied_params

equals 14 and I'm only using 13 coefficients?
I have read similar questions and this one but haven't figured this out yet.

It is the error variance which is needed for fully specifying the Gaussian log likelihood.

The constant difference comes from the fact that the formula used to compute the fitted values in an AR model substracts the intercept from each lagged value multiplied by the respective AR parameter.
I deduced this from the Details section of the ar() documentation in the stats package, where it states:

For definiteness, note that the AR coefficients have the sign in
x[t] - m = a[1](x[t-1] - m) + … + a[p](x[t-p] - m) + e[t]

So, to obtain the same fitted values, you should use the following piece of code to compute calcFitted10:
calcFitted10 <- numeric(10)
for (i in 351:360) {
  calcFitted10[i-350] <- sum((window_data[(i-12):(i-1)] - ar_model$coef[13]) * ar_model$coef[12:1]) + ar_model$coef[13]
}
fitted10 - calcFitted10

I obtained the following array as the difference between fitted10 and calcFitted10 when I ran the code:
> fitted10 - calcFitted10
 [1] -2.168404e-19  1.951564e-18 -8.673617e-19  0.000000e+00 -1.734723e-18 8.673617e-19 -6.505213e-19 -2.168404e-19
 [9] -1.301043e-18  0.000000e+00

